# Translate are not working for standard admin

Tags: actions, translation

I'm developing a plugin which uses strings of the "default" textdomain, but several strings will not shown translated.

My locale language is "de_DE" (german).
I try to access the word "Count", which is available inside the "admin-de_DE.po" file. (To make sure, the loaded .mo file is actual, I compiled it with Poedit and Loco for debugging.)
Other strings of that file will be shown translated, for example "[Pending]" as "[Ausstehend]", but not "Count" as "Anzahl".

What is my mistake?

```
add_action( 'admin_init', 'action_admin_init' );
function action_admin_init() {
  _e( 'Count' );
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only instance of `"Count"` I can see in the default domain's admin file has a context value of `"Number/count of items"`. So your code should be:

```
add_action( 'admin_init', 'action_admin_init' );
function action_admin_init() {
  _ex( 'Count', 'Number/count of items' );
}
```

Ref: [_ex](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/_ex/).